# Importing a single large Google Drive archive into a shared Google Colab project

Tags: machine-learning, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I am working on a class project where we're working with a large dataset in Google Colabs. Notably, the file is not saved if the runtime disconnects. I thus downloaded the dataset to my personal drive, but am struggling to get it accessible to the Colabs project. I also can't just mount my drive because there are other people working on this.

Is there some way to download a link-sharing=on drive file in Colabs?

A way to save the trained model would also be useful, but the same issue of sharing it and the saved files still applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways that I know.

If you only want to share with your friends, not making it public, you can share via google drive. Each friend will need to `auth.authenticate_user()` and then use `pydrive` to load the file given its `FILE_ID`.

If you can make it public, it's even easier. Anyone can download the file with

```
!gdown --id xxxxxxxxx
```

Where `xxxxxxx` is the FILE_ID.

Comment: The second one was exactly what I was looking for there.